# Create and display different data after perform a cell selection in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to add student name by clicking a button after selecting Class cell in the previous TableView, the problem I'm facing is, for example, I have three classes, class A, B, C. Then I choose class A to create student X, but then when I go back to class B or class C, I also see student X inside those classes. I realized that I use the same data for all classes, but I'm not able to fix this.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class StudentListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var studentList = [StudentData]()

var student: StudentData?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<StudentData> = StudentData.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let studentList = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.studentList = studentList
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {}

}

@IBAction func addStudentTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Student", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (studentListTF) in
        studentListTF.placeholder = "Enter name"
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in
        guard let student = alert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
        print(student)
        let person = StudentData(context: PersistenceService.context)
        person.student_name = student
        PersistenceService.saveContext()
        self.studentList.append(person)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert,animated: true)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return studentList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let stuCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "studentCell", for: indexPath)

    stuCell.textLabel?.text = studentList[indexPath.row].student_name

    return stuCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard editingStyle == .delete else {return}
    let person = studentList[indexPath.row]
    studentList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    PersistenceService.context.delete(person)
    PersistenceService.saveContext()

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<StudentData> = StudentData.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let studentList = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.studentList = studentList
    } catch {}
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print("Delete \(person)")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any code line that you filter class for your List Student.
I think your class StudentData miss variable " class " to show that which class the student are in.
Then for your tableView, you have 2 option:

- Fetch all students one time then create showArray to keep all student in 1 class by :

  self.showArray = studentList.filter{$0.class == "A"}
- Fetch data by class with CoreData NSPredicate:

  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "class = %@", "A")